# EntityFramework.Extended on EF6 derived types

Tags: entity-framework-6, entityframework.extended

Consider the following EF entities:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string LocationDescription { get; set; }
}

public class LocationHolding : Location
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string LocationDescriptionHolding { get; set; }
}
```

The context is derived from `DbContext` and has a single `DbSet`:

```
public IDbSet<Location> Location { get; set; }
```

Using the `EntityFramework.Extended` package, upon attempting a batch update:

```
context.Location
    .OfType<LocationHolding>()
    .Where(x => true)
    .Update(u => new LocationHolding
    {
        LocationDescription = u.LocationDescriptionHolding
    });
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
There are no EntitySets defined for the specified entity type 'TestEfHierarchy.Model.LocationHolding'.
If 'TestEfHierarchy.Model.LocationHolding' is a derived type, use the base type instead.
Parameter name: TEntity
```

Whilst having success with the package against simple single entities, I've been unable to find an examples where this has been used in more complex situations.

For the entity hierarchy, both table-per-hierarchy and table-per-type have been tried, both with the same result. The only situation I have found to work is when updating with static values (i.e. LocationDescription = "Foo") and the hierarchy is TPH.

Has anybody had similar experiences or found alternative workarounds? Appreciate that alternative methods such as stored procedures are available, but would like to use a code based/fluent approach.